# installing apex in Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, apex

I want to install apex on Windows. However, it fails and the following message appears:

```
Collecting apex
  Using cached apex-0.9.10dev.tar.gz (36 kB)
Collecting cryptacular
  Using cached cryptacular-1.5.5.tar.gz (39 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdqtwvtby'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ada3d474ab4e459b9ce2bdb8db71864f
    Complete output (50 lines):
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ada3d474ab4e459b9ce2bdb8db71864f\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ada3d474ab4e459b9ce2bdb8db71864f\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>
    DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat:
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ada3d474ab4e459b9ce2bdb8db71864f\SConstruct", line 25:
        env = Environment(
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1013:
        apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 116:
        env.Tool(tool)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1871:
        tool(self)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 108:
        ext = get_build_ext()
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 84:
        cmd.run()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340:
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449:
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474:
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 64:
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529:
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323:
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220:
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 122:
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 35, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _run("dist_info")
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o7y14ah2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 29, in _run
        lookup = SCons.Node.arg2nodes_lookups[0](alias).sources[0]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sources'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/d6/a82d191ec058314b2b7cbee5635150f754ba1c6ffc05387bc9a57efe48b8/cryptacular-1.5.5.tar.gz#sha256=fb4d48716e88e4d050255ff0f065f6d437caa358ceef16ba5840c95cece224f9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cryptacular/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdqtwvtby' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached cryptacular-1.5.1.tar.gz (39 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvsrq5fqq'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_85e13ce853874f05a67d852b03fc0866
    Complete output (50 lines):
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_85e13ce853874f05a67d852b03fc0866\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_85e13ce853874f05a67d852b03fc0866\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>
    DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat:
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_85e13ce853874f05a67d852b03fc0866\SConstruct", line 25:
        env = Environment(
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1013:
        apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 116:
        env.Tool(tool)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1871:
        tool(self)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 108:
        ext = get_build_ext()
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 84:
        cmd.run()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340:
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449:
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474:
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 64:
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529:
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323:
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220:
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 122:
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 35, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _run("dist_info")
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hblsgl2m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 29, in _run
        lookup = SCons.Node.arg2nodes_lookups[0](alias).sources[0]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sources'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/19/6f3276ee6013db5f3e091b733de21b7ac7f9af0465732f07cf0f03dac300/cryptacular-1.5.1.tar.gz#sha256=f5d3d0917ad24705bcb7cf9e91cafaf49705718bc41f2794f471f136f50e8219 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cryptacular/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvsrq5fqq' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached cryptacular-1.5.0.tar.gz (39 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2suixd7n'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ccbe4935c0e848eebc3dc1d111d00f06
    Complete output (50 lines):
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ccbe4935c0e848eebc3dc1d111d00f06\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>

    scons: warning: VC version 14.2 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
     Installed versions are: []
    File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ccbe4935c0e848eebc3dc1d111d00f06\SConstruct", line 25, in <module>
    DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat:
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_ccbe4935c0e848eebc3dc1d111d00f06\SConstruct", line 25:
        env = Environment(
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1013:
        apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 116:
        env.Tool(tool)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Environment.py", line 1871:
        tool(self)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 108:
        ext = get_build_ext()
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 84:
        cmd.run()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340:
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449:
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474:
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\cpyext.py", line 64:
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529:
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323:
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220:
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 122:
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 35, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return _run("dist_info")
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_u9jstmn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\enscons\api.py", line 29, in _run
        lookup = SCons.Node.arg2nodes_lookups[0](alias).sources[0]
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sources'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/96/0b7b9ceb01c7754f602d26ef6703e89b48275970c50e773dda68d38581b1/cryptacular-1.5.0.tar.gz#sha256=a154c672a833d40ccad6820f7307be5816db66fd3544507b99c3d91a8c59fde8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cryptacular/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2suixd7n' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached cryptacular-1.4.1.tar.gz (40 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.sqlalchemy in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: velruse>=1.0.3 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyramid>1.1.2 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyramid_mailer in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (2.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms-recaptcha in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from apex) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: hupper>=1.5 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (1.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: plaster-pastedeploy in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: webob>=1.8.3 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (1.8.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.deprecation>=3.5.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: translationstring>=0.4 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=3.8.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: venusian>=1.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: plaster in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from velruse>=1.0.3->apex) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: anykeystore in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from velruse>=1.0.3->apex) (0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-openid in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from velruse>=1.0.3->apex) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pbkdf2 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptacular->apex) (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PasteDeploy>=2.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaster-pastedeploy->pyramid>1.1.2->apex) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: transaction in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid_mailer->apex) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: repoze.sendmail>=4.1 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyramid_mailer->apex) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python3-openid->velruse>=1.0.3->apex) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->apex) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->apex) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->apex) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests->apex) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib->velruse>=1.0.3->apex) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from wtforms->apex) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy!=1.4.0,!=1.4.1,!=1.4.2,!=1.4.3,!=1.4.4,!=1.4.5,!=1.4.6,>=0.9 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from zope.sqlalchemy->apex) (1.4.20)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from SQLAlchemy!=1.4.0,!=1.4.1,!=1.4.2,!=1.4.3,!=1.4.4,!=1.4.5,!=1.4.6,>=0.9->zope.sqlalchemy->apex) (1.1.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for apex, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cryptacular, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: cryptacular, apex
    Running setup.py install for cryptacular ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipbr8slh\\cryptacular_0d811b25006c476d8433f0eb9be51325\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipbr8slh\\cryptacular_0d811b25006c476d8433f0eb9be51325\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w5pfqvzi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cryptacular'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipbr8slh\cryptacular_0d811b25006c476d8433f0eb9be51325\
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular
    copying cryptacular\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\bcrypt
    copying cryptacular\bcrypt\test_bcrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\bcrypt
    copying cryptacular\bcrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\bcrypt
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\core
    copying cryptacular\core\test_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\core
    copying cryptacular\core\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\core
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\crypt
    copying cryptacular\crypt\test_crypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\crypt
    copying cryptacular\crypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\crypt
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\pbkdf2
    copying cryptacular\pbkdf2\test_pbkdf2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\pbkdf2
    copying cryptacular\pbkdf2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\pbkdf2
    running egg_info
    writing cryptacular.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to cryptacular.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing namespace_packages to cryptacular.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
    writing requirements to cryptacular.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to cryptacular.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'cryptacular.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'cryptacular.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying cryptacular\bcrypt\_bcrypt.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cryptacular\bcrypt
    running build_ext
    building 'cryptacular.bcrypt._bcrypt' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipbr8slh\\cryptacular_0d811b25006c476d8433f0eb9be51325\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ipbr8slh\\cryptacular_0d811b25006c476d8433f0eb9be51325\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w5pfqvzi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\cryptacular' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix this problem and install this package? I have both tried to install it in command prompt using "pip" and from the settings in Pycharm but neither of them was successful. I have also tried the following but it wasn't successful either.

```
pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" .
```

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. Did you get anything new?

Comment: btw, i think this thread may help you, installing Apex this way worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127273/failing-to-pip3-install-apex-down-to-failure-to-build-cryptacular-installed

Comment: cd apex
pip3 setup.py install